# Disable code highlighting in RStudio 2023.03.0 Build 386

Tags: rstudio

I can't find options how to turn off "color code" highlighting in `R Studio  2023.03.0 Build 386`
can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @zx8754
 Very, very contrasts with the rest of the code, does not allow you to focus ..
I like this idea, but not the implementation.


if the text itself was in color, and not the background behind the text, it would probably be ideal

Comment: Probably because of dark mode, colours stand out too much. Maybe worth submitting a feature request at GitHub for text colouring instead of background.

Comment: I don't know, I think the developers tried different options, but for some reason they chose this one. I can’t speak for everyone, if I don’t like something, it doesn’t mean that it’s bad for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Global Options` -> `Code` -> `Display` and uncheck "Enable preview of named and hexadecimal colors" under `Syntax`.

[image]